# How does a site redirect existing tab when visiting it in a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I am trying to open a page from [Course Report](https://www.coursereport.com/) in a new tab. Usually I would do this as follows:

```
<a href="https://www.coursereport.com/schools/flatiron-school" target="_blank">https://www.coursereport.com/schools/flatiron-school</a>
```

However course report is doing something strange. If I use that link, it:

- Briefly opens the tab correctly
- The tab closes
- The original tab (where I clicked the link) redirects to course report

I am interested in

- How course report achieves this (it seems bad that a new tab can have that much control over the referring tab)
- What I can do to prevent this and get the default behaviour instead.

I can't seem to reproduce directly in stackoverflow but here is a HackMD document where you can see the behaviour [https://hackmd.io/s/Hy1Ln7g8X](https://hackmd.io/s/Hy1Ln7g8X#)

Comment: It's weird, there's absolutely no reason why the tab would close itself, then the requested page be loaded in the original tab. I've tried in a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/mjgpOP), it works as intended. It looks like some dark JS is being automatically attached to your link somehow.

Comment: hmmm, a link to a site with "hack" in the name - and it behaves oddly - yeah, won't be going there matey - if you can replicate this behaviour in say, jsfiddle or codepen or any other reputable site, then I'll check it out

Comment: yeah, code is clean, its work fine on my editor, i think its due to events listeners on hackmd web platform.

Comment: hackmd.io looks dodgy af but it's just a markdown editor (and a really good one). You can create your own .html page locally and copy my html snippet if you want to test it out locally. It's nothing to do with hackmd -- it happens everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Reproducing the behaviour

- [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) *returns a reference to the window that opened this current window*
- the current window can be closed with [`window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close)

So **you can reproduce** the behaviour by creating 2 files:

1.html

```
<a href="2.html" target="_blank">Go to second page</a>
```

2.html

```
<script>
window.opener.location="about:blank";
window.close();
</script>
```

Rewriting the source tab from the target page can be used as [reverse tabnabbing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Reverse_Tabnabbing) and it can be dangerous.

> Reverse tabnabbing is an attack where a page linked from the target page is able to rewrite that page, for example to replace it with a phishing site. As the user was originally on the correct page they are less likely to notice that it has been changed to a phishing site, especially it the site looks the same as the target.

## Preventing the behaviour

As `window.opener`'s documentation says, **you can prevent this** behaviour with an attribute, but this works only in some browsers (Firefox 52+, Chrome 49+, Opera 36+, Safari 10.1+):

> In [some browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=noopener), a `rel="noopener"` attribute on the originating anchor tag will prevent the window.opener reference from being set.

```
<a href="2.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Go to second page</a>
```

I found also [this page](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/) about `rel=noopener` which mentions possible solutions for older browsers too:

> For older browsers, you could use `rel=noreferrer` which also disables the Referer HTTP header, or the following JavaScript work-around which potentially triggers the popup blocker:
>
> ```
> var otherWindow = window.open();
> otherWindow.opener = null;
> otherWindow.location = url;
> ```

You can combine values for the `rel` attribute like `rel="noreferrer noopener"`.

Comment: Some IDE linters/plugins have started warning about this behaviour/bug, it's a good one to be aware of!

Comment: Thanks, very informative. It seems insane to me that a tab can set the location for its opener..

Comment: You're welcome! :) I agree on that it's insane. This is called [reverse tabnabbing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Reverse_Tabnabbing) and can be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

There is a click event on Body in your Javascriptcode. This is the problem i think.